# How do I make pygames play audio from a folder?

Tags: python, pygame

Hello I'm new to programming and I wanted to make a song player.

```
import os
from pygame import mixer
Path = input("please provide path to folder: ")
os.chdir(Path)
mixer.init()
mixer.music.load.(Path)
```

This is my code so far.

Answer (score 0):

Here I speacified the folder containing all the song and you just only need to input the specific song name.**(Always use '\' while giving path)**

```
import pygame
pygame.mixer.init()
song=str(input('Song Name: ')) #ask for song name
path='C:\\folder_name\\'+song 

pygame.mixer.music.load(path)
pygame.mixer.music.play(loops=3) #how many times to repeat the song
```

Answer (score 0):

Your need to make sure the program isn't exiting.So add a while loop.Hope this answer helps you.

```
from pygame import mixer
Path = input("please provide path to folder: ")
mixer.init()
mixer.music.load(Path)
# Setting the volume 
mixer.music.set_volume(0.7) 

# Start playing the song 
mixer.music.play() 
# infinite loop 
while True: 
  
    print("Press 'p' to pause, 'r' to resume") 
    print("Press 'e' to exit the program") 
    query = input("  ") 
  
    if query == 'p': 
        # Pausing the music 
        mixer.music.pause()      
    elif query == 'r': 

        # Resuming the music 
        mixer.music.unpause() 
    elif query == 'e': 

        # Stop the mixer 
        mixer.music.stop() 
        break
```

Comment: you coded the whole thing for me. ;-; That is my fault hahaha but I was trying to do this a a fun project